# Removing the string from already captured group regex

Tags: regex, bash

Need to get regex for the following with these conditions:

The captured group will contain the output expected, if "GM5" is present in string, it should not come in final capture group

CURRENT:

- 123456_GM5_testing.csv
- 123456_GM5_ekko.csv.json
- 123456_TN_TECH_CHECK_IMAGES.csv
- 213456_TN_TECH_CHECK_IMAGES.csv.json

OUTPUT expected:

- testing.csv
- ekko.csv.json
- TN_TECH_CHECK_IMAGES.csv
- TN_TECH_CHECK_IMAGES.csv.json

Current Solution: `([A-Z].+)`

Issue: 'GM5' is still in captured group that need to be removed

Comment: Are you doing it in Oracle? `regexp-replace` tag is used when you code in Oracle. If yes, just add the relevant tag.

Comment: No, I am changing file name using this regex in bash

Comment: Would something like that do the trick? `_[A-Za-z._]*$`  https://regex101.com/r/y0YeGd/1

Comment: try this ([A-Z])\w+.*

Comment: visit this link so you can try your regex without executing your code https://regexr.com/53bjl

Comment: @yoss, I am still getting 'GM5' in captured group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bash, you may use

```
rx='(_GM5)?_(.*)'
```

The regex will match an optional sequence `_GM5` (capturing it in Group 1, mind that Bash POSIX ERE syntax does not support non-capturing groups), and then `_` will get matched and the rest of string will get captured into Group 2, and you may get this value using `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}`.

See the [online Bash demo](https://ideone.com/PVY6nZ):

```
#!/bin/bash
s="123456_GM5_testing.csv
123456_GM5_ekko.csv.json
123456_TN_TECH_CHECK_IMAGES.csv
213456_TN_TECH_CHECK_IMAGES.csv.json"

rx='(_GM5)?_(.*)'
while read -r line
do
  if [[ "$line" =~ $rx ]]; then
    echo "$line => ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}";
  fi;
done <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
123456_GM5_testing.csv => testing.csv
123456_GM5_ekko.csv.json => ekko.csv.json
123456_TN_TECH_CHECK_IMAGES.csv => TN_TECH_CHECK_IMAGES.csv
213456_TN_TECH_CHECK_IMAGES.csv.json => TN_TECH_CHECK_IMAGES.csv.json
```

If you need a `sed` solution use

```
sed 's/^[^_]*\(_GM5\)\{0,1\}_//'
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/zF4XxH)

Comment: @Ashutoshgupta Exactly, there is one line of regex - `rx='(_GM5)?_(.*)'`. But you need to get the match somehow. [You said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61442971/removing-the-string-from-already-captured-group-regex/61443219#comment108690783_61442971) you were using Bash, you got the solution for Bash.

Comment: Actually I have to use this expressing in Nifi, to extract the value of current variable. So there can't be multiple steps on that.

Comment: @Ashutoshgupta So, what tool are you using?

Comment: In Apache Nifi while configuring processor, I need to set a property from the another available variable mentioned as inputs

Comment: @Ashutoshgupta I added a `sed` solution, `sed 's/^[^_]*\(_GM5\)\{0,1\}_//'`

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiktor. I am trying to check your regex here. regexr.com/53bk7 . It seem to be not giving answer. Can you please have a look?

Comment: @Ashutoshgupta No need to have a look at the regex tester for JS or PCRE if you are using Bash. Show how you are using a regex in the **target environment**.

Comment: If you are using `${filename:replaceAll(regex,replacement)}`, use `${filename:replaceAll('(_GM5)?_(.*)','$2')}`

Comment: Thank a lot. I think it will work in NIFI. I will check in my pipeline and update you. Thanks.

Comment: @Ashutoshgupta Yes, also please after checking and letting know, change your question tags, and add the exact method/function you used.